# Python3 os.open with fcntl.LOCK_EX not working

Tags: locking, python-3.4

It seems that os.open() doesn't work with fcntl.LOCK_EX properly. My test code to reproduce it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import fcntl, os, signal, time

os.fork()

class TimeoutException(Exception): pass

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException()

while True:
    try:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
        signal.alarm(5)
        f = os.open("python3.4-flock-test", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
        fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        print(os.getpid(), "write to file")
        os.write(f, bytes("test", "utf-8"))
        time.sleep(1)
        fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        os.close(f)
        signal.alarm(0)
    except TimeoutException:
        print(os.getpid(), "flock runs on a timeout")
```

The output is as example:

```
# ./flock-test
21819 write to file
21819 write to file
21819 write to file
21819 write to file
21819 write to file
21818 flock runs on a timeout
21819 write to file
21819 write to file
```

Does anyone has a explantation why the following code snipped doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

'os.open' works perfectly fine in that example, but instead of os.O_RDWR , you need to O_WRONLY.